# SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error:

Tags: android-sqlite

I am getting this error

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "SELECT": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT _id, c_type, s_name, s_numb, user_name, password FROM accounts WHERE SELECT * FROM TableName LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Here is the code the code that creates the problem . My intent is to get the ROWID of `ith` record from the table and then use that ROWID to delete an entry from the table.

```
public void deleteEntry(long i) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CTYPE, KEY_SNAME, KEY_SNUMB, KEY_USRN, KEY_PASS};
    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE,columns,"SELECT * FROM " +DATABASE_TABLE+" LIMIT 1 OFFSET "+i, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        long rowIds = cursor.getLong(0);
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowIds, null);
    }
  //  ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_SNUMB + "=" + siteNum, null);
    //return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,cv);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ith record? THe query looks wrong in the where filter

Comment: I am passing `int i` in the parameters if `i =5' then I need 5th record.

Answer (score 1):

I achieved the result by changing the approach, but as I am learning android and am a beginner I would like to know how to fix the code I mentioned in the question

```
String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CTYPE, KEY_SNAME, KEY_SNUMB, KEY_USRN, KEY_PASS};
    Cursor cursor = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for(int x=0;x<i;x++)
        {
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        long rowIds = cursor.getLong(0);
        ourDatabase.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowIds, null);
    }
```